# Cypress error when testing nested iframes in headless mode - race condition

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress, e2e-testing

I am testing a web app and the test runs reliably in headed mode (`cypress open`) but has errors in headless mode (`cypress run`), so it's likely a race condition that I cannot resolve. The error message is:

`[36819:0223/163815.745047:ERROR:system_services.cc(34)] SetApplicationIsDaemon: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "paramErr: error in user parameter list" (-50)`

This error is mentioned again when Cypress creates a video of the incident:

```
-  Started processing:  Compressing to 32 CRF                                                     
2022-02-23 17:00:19.700 Cypress Helper[37571:416134] In -[NSApplication(NSQuietSafeQuit) _updateCanQuitQuietlyAndSafely], _LSSetApplicationInformationItem(NSCanQuitQuietlyAndSafely) returned error -50
-  Finished processing: /Users/malte.wirz/Documents/iframes-cypress-issue/cypress/videos/iframe-github.js.mp4     (3 seconds)
```

I created a demo repository [here](https://github.com/maltewirz/cypress-iframes). To reproduce, clone it, run `yarn` to install, and `yarn cypress:run`. The test does pass, but with the error mentioned above.

I assume that the error stems from accessing the nested iframes and I tested 5 different approaches so far, but to no avail. I especially made sure that the function `getIframeBody` waits until each iframe and the requested element is ready. The error also creates a video, but you can only see the successful run, the error message is not visible there.

Any help on how to debug this further is much appreciated.

```
describe('Testing Iframe within Iframes', () => {
    it('Visits the iframe website and accesses the iframe within the iframe', () => {
      const getIframeBody = (iframeSelector, elementSelectorInIframe) => {
        return cy
        .get(iframeSelector)
        .its('0.contentDocument.body', {timeout: 30000})
        .should((body) => {
          expect(Cypress.$(body).has(elementSelectorInIframe).length).gt(0)
        })
        .then(cy.wrap)
      }

      // Visiting the page index.html and getting iframe A
      cy.visit('index.html').contains('XHR in iframe')
      getIframeBody('iframe[data-cy="bankid"]', 'iframe[src="https://tools.bankid.no/bankid-test/auth"]').as('iframeA')

      cy.get('@iframeA').within(() => {
        getIframeBody('iframe[src="https://tools.bankid.no/bankid-test/auth"]', 'iframe[src^="https://csfe.bankid.no/CentralServerFEJS"]').as('iframeB')

        cy.get('@iframeB').within(() => {
          getIframeBody('iframe[src^="https://csfe.bankid.no/CentralServerFEJS"]', 'input[type="tel"]').as('iframeC')

          // Now we are in the right place and it finds the correct input element.
          // However, normal cypress command .type() fails and we have to use library cypress-real-events,
          // which provides an event firing system that works literally like in puppeteer
          cy.get('@iframeC').find('input[type="tel"]').should('be.visible').realType('12345678912')

          // But for the button below, this library now doesn't help anymore:
          // "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."
          // This was solved by using {scrollBehavior:false}.
          cy.get('@iframeC').find('button[type="submit"]').should('be.visible').first().realClick({scrollBehavior:false})
        })
      })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some feedback that the above "ERROR:system_services.cc(34)" is not critical and does not cause flaky or unsuccessful tests, therefore there are no action points.